# Android java NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

```
public class Database extends Activity {

private TextView tvInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
private Button btnInfo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnInfo);
```

Hello guys, probably this is just an newbie error in java, but why is this throwing me a NPE? I'm just declaring those variables and it gives me an NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to code like below

```
private TextView tvInfo = null;
private Button btnInfo = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.configuration);
            tvInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
            btnInfo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnInfo);
            ........
    }
```

Try above scenario, you will not get `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find a view unless it is available. This is why you should move your code as follows:

```
private TextView tvInfo;
private Button btnInfo;
```

inside the onCreate method, you do:

```
tvInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
btnInfo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

did you call `setContentView(R.layout.main)` beforehand your declerations?
I'm not quite sure what exactly has to be called, but it seems your Resources may are just not set.

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem, now I understand, got no Java experience before!

Comment: Mark your question answered to prevent more answers for solved problems ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should be initializing the variables inside onCreate() after calling setContentView

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem! Stupid newbie mistake :)

Comment: your welcome. remember to accept answers  you have found  useful. The person who answered gets points (10) as do you (2)

Answer (score 0):

Override onCreate method of the activity and set the layout of the activity through setContentView and then try finding TextView and Button.